# sql server - process group of values most efficiently way possible

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a server app (written in c++ using Qt, same for clients), that serves 6 different types of clinets (over TCP/IP), those clients use one database (sql server).
clients can ask the server to perform certain queries using XML.
I can't send more than one statement in one query.

I am stuck with a problem

## the goal is to:

- load data from a csv file (about 8000+ records); (it takes 67ms)
- check for them in the Database (in about 4 tables) if they can passes some evaluations;
- insert them in a certain table if they pass the evaluations;
- send to client the processing result.

my solution is to read the whole set of values and pass it to db to be processed then recieve a result.

since I am not that expert of sql server performance, and the whole set of his available tools, I would love to ask for your opinion.

## how it could be done in sql server more effeciently?

1. either pass the parsed values as a string to a sql server procedure

> "('v11', 'v12', 'v13',..., 'v17'), ...,('vn1', 'vn2', 'vn3',..., 'vn7')"

2. or insert them in a table to be procceded by the procedure using cursor or any other way available.

## if it is the 1-st solution then:

- how to iterate through it (efficiently)?
- is it possible to pass them as a different type (that could speed up the process)?

I don't know which is best, since I am not an expert in databases. I use c++ more than sql in about 90%.

## I am looking for the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoever intrested in optimizing, I have came up with the next solution, which gives me executing time of less than 1 second (I used sets approch, I have tested it on 22000+ records, it took sligtly more than 1 sec), compared to 9 min using the approch that our database "speciallist" came up with and had exponetial growth up to 1 hour on our production database.

- I had to process 8000+ records.
- Evaluate each record in 4 tables.
- Insert the record into a target table if it passes evaluations.

please consider what I came up to when making such approch:

1. Use sets approch whenever is possible (**avoid** cursor).
2. Insert all data in one buffer table `dbo.buff`. (no more than 1000 records in each insert).
3. Create a procedure that will do:

   - create temp table to hold the id of records that passes your evaluation.
   - save the id from `dbo.buff` into temp table

     `INSERT INTO @temp as tmp SELECT id
     FROM dbo.buff LEFT JOIN <tables, in which you need to evaluate your records>
     ON <evaluatin conditions> 
     WHERE <tables>.id IS NOT NULL <any more conditions>`
   - avoid operator `OR` any where in your code (if you are working with large sets), it is a lot better to repeat the `INSERT` query but with condition you wanted to add after `OR` (in my condition there was a huge drop in performance when I added `OR` (from less than 1 sec to 11 sec).
   - finally it does:

     `INSERT INTO target_table (fields) 
     SELECT (fields) FROM @tmp as tmp 
     INNER JOIN dbo.buff AS bf ON tmp.id = bf.id`
   - you can return an integer value to indicate if all the records passed the evaluations or not (for further processing, it dependes on you)

Every time you have to process this amount of records, you insert them into the buffer table and then you call the procedure.

This solution is way faster then check for every record.

P.S. I am sorry if I didn't declare all the details in my question (I understatnd that it is really abstract and my goal really depends on the details). I am just not allowed to share them.